# How to access XY position of text element in Layout view using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#, layouts

I'm wondering which interface will allow me to set the XY position of a text element in the page layout of my MXD. I have tried the IElement.Geometry.Envelope.PutCoords(Y, X) to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to move text elements around the page layout is to use ITransform2D. Below is some VBA showing how to do it:

```vb
Public Sub TextElementExample()
    ' Get map document
    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
    Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument

    ' Get Pagelayout
    Dim pPageLayout As IPageLayout
    Set pPageLayout = pMxDoc.PageLayout

    ' Get Graphics container
    Dim pGraphicsContainer As IGraphicsContainer
    Set pGraphicsContainer = pPageLayout

    ' Create a point in page layout units
    Dim pPoint As IPoint
    Set pPoint = New Point
    pPoint.X = 10
    pPoint.Y = 10

    ' Create sample text
    Dim pTextElement As ITextElement
    Set pTextElement = New TextElement
    pTextElement.Text = "Some Sample Text"
    pTextElement.ScaleText = True

    'Add text to page layout
    Dim pElement As IElement
    Set pElement = pTextElement
    pElement.Geometry = pPoint
    pGraphicsContainer.AddElement pElement, 0

    ' Clone text element
    Dim pClone As IClone
    Set pClone = pElement
    Dim pElement2 As IElement
    Set pElement2 = pClone.Clone

    ' Now move new element and add to pagelayout
    Dim pTransform2D As ITransform2D
    Set pTransform2D = pElement2
    pTransform2D.Move 10, -5
    pGraphicsContainer.AddElement pElement2, 0

End Sub
```

Comment: This will certainly work! I was also wondering if there's a way to set/get the XY position properties of the text element. I recall from ArcPy that you can simply set the elementPositionX/Y properties to perform the transformation, do you know of an ArcObjects equivalent?